# Opencv and Python on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I copy a code from a Web page to Python 2.7 but I didn't success.

The code is:

```
# Raspbery Pi Color Tracking Project
# Code written by Oscar Liang
# 30 Jun 2013

import cv2.cv as cv
import smbus

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

def sendData(value):
bus.write_byte(address, value)
# bus.write_byte_data(address, 0, value)
return -1

def readData():
state = bus.read_byte(address)
# number = bus.read_byte_data(address, 1)
return state

def ColorProcess(img):

# returns thresholded image
imgHSV = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 3)

# converts BGR image to HSV
cv.CvtColor(img, imgHSV, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
imgProcessed = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 1)

# converts the pixel values lying within the range to 255 and stores it in the destination
cv.InRangeS(imgHSV, (100, 94, 84), (109, 171, 143), imgProcessed)
return imgProcessed

def main():

# captured image size, change to whatever you want
width = 320
height = 240

capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)

# Over-write default captured image size
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,width)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,height)

cv.NamedWindow( “output”, 1 )
cv.NamedWindow( “processed”, 1 )

while True:

frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
cv.Smooth(frame, frame, cv.CV_BLUR, 3)

imgColorProcessed = ColorProcess(frame)
mat = cv.GetMat(imgColorProcessed)

# Calculating the moments
moments = cv.Moments(mat, 0)
area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0)
moment10 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)
moment01 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0,1)

# Finding a big enough blob
if(area > 60000):

# Calculating the center postition of the blob
posX = int(moment10 / area)
posY = int(moment01 / area)

# check slave status and send coordinates
state = readData()
if state == 1:
sendData(posX)
sendData(posY)
print ‘x: ‘ + str(posX) + ‘ y: ‘ + str(posY)

# update video windows
cv.ShowImage(“processed”, imgColorProcessed)
cv.ShowImage(“output”, frame)

if cv.WaitKey(10) >= 0:
break

return;

if __name__ == “__main__”:
main()
```

Comment: In what way were you not successful? Do you get errors when you run this? What happens?

Comment: Hmm, if this code is indented how you have it in your editor, then you need to fix you indentation - Python [needs indentation to work](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html).

Comment: Yes I get many errors some of them about indentation and other about function...I fixed indentation but functions errors I couldn't.

Comment: OK, please post the new version, and _exactly_ the errors you get, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The right code is:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import smbus
import cv2
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

def sendData(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    return -1
def readData():
    state = bus.read_byte(address)
    return state
def ColorProcess(img):
    imgHSV = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img) ,8 ,3)
    cv.CvtColor(img, imgHSV, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
    imgProcessed = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img) ,8 ,1)
    cv.InRangeS(imgHSV, (100, 94, 84), (109, 171, 143), imgProcessed)
    return imgProcessed
def main():
    width = 320
    height = 240

    capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
    cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    cv.NamedWindow("output", 1)
    cv.NamedWindow("processed", 1)

    while True:
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        cv.Smooth(frame, frame, cv.CV_BLUR, 3)
        imgColorProcessed = ColorProcess(frame)
        mat = cv.GetMat(imgColorProcessed)
        moments = cv.Moments(mat, 0)
        area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0)
        moment10 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)
        moment01 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1)

        if (area > 60000):
            posX = int(moment10/area)
            posY = int(moment01/area)
            ali = long(2000000)

            state = readData()
            if state == 1:
                sendData(posX)
                sendData(posY)

            print 'x: ' + str(posX) + 'y: ' + str(posY)

        cv.ShowImage("processed", imgColorProcessed)
        cv.ShowImage("output", frame)

        if cv.WaitKey(10) >= 0:

            break

    return;

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```